# Getting Error Trying to Implement Object Detection with Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

Project I'm looking at is: https://github.com/mdietrichstein/tensorflow-open_nsfw

I pulled the code and when I run it I get the following error (specific file being run below as well):

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "classify_nsfw.py", line 58, in

main(sys.argv)

File "classify_nsfw.py", line 37, in main
    with tf.Session() as sess:

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'Session'

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys
import argparse
import tensorflow as tf

from model import OpenNsfwModel, InputType
from image_utils import create_tensorflow_image_loader
from image_utils import create_yahoo_image_loader
import cv2
import time
import os

import numpy as np

def main(argv):
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    parser.add_argument("input_file", help="Path to the input image.\
                        Only jpeg images are supported.")

    parser.add_argument("-m", "--model_weights", required=True,
                        help="Path to trained model weights file")


    parser.add_argument("-i", "--input_type",
                        default=InputType.TENSOR.name.lower(),
                        help="input type",
                        choices=[InputType.TENSOR.name.lower(),
                                 InputType.BASE64_JPEG.name.lower()])

    args = parser.parse_args()

    model = OpenNsfwModel()

    with tf.Session() as sess:

        input_type = InputType[args.input_type.upper()]

        model.build(weights_path=args.model_weights, input_type=input_type)
        fn_load_image = None

        if input_type == InputType.TENSOR:
            fn_load_image = create_yahoo_image_loader()
        if input_type == InputType.BASE64_JPEG:
            import base64
            fn_load_image = lambda filename: np.array([base64.urlsafe_b64encode(open(filename, "rb").read())])

        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

        image = fn_load_image(args.input_file)
        predictions = sess.run(model.predictions, feed_dict={model.input: image})
        print("Results for '{}'".format(args.input_file))
        print("\tSFW score:\t{}\n\tNSFW score:\t{}".format(*predictions[0]))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main(sys.argv)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is you are using old TensorFlow **1.X** syntax. `tf.Session()` was deprecated in TensorFlow **2.0.0**.

The module `tf.compat.v1` brings in all of the public TensorFlow interface. If you still want to use `tf.Session()`, use the syntax `tf.compat.v1.Session()` instead.

Comment: Thanks so much I was following an old tutorial and didn't realize the syntax changed